# Standard deep nested data type?

Tags: abap, saprfc, pyrfc

I took the nice example [clientPrintDescription.py](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC/blob/master/examples/clientPrintDescription.py) and create a HTML form from the description which matches the input data types for the particular RFC function.

In SAP data types can contain data types which can contain data types, and I want to test my HTML form generator with a very nested data type.

Of course I could create my own custom data type, but it would be more re-usable if I would use an existing (rfc-capable) data type.

Which data type in SAP contains a lot of nested data types? And maybe a lot of different data types?

Answer (score 5):

I cannot tell which structure is the best for your case but you could filter the view `DD03VV` (now that is a meaningful name) using the transaction `se16h`. If you `GROUP BY` the column `TABNAME` and filter on `WHERE TABCLASS = 'INTTAB'` the number of entries is an indicator for the size of the structure.

You could also aggregate and in a next step filter on the maximum `DEPTH` value (like a SQL `HAVING`, which afaik does not exist in SAP R/3). On my system the maximum depth is 12.

**Edit**: If you cannot access `se16h`, here's a workaround: Call `se37` and execute  `SE16N_START` with `I_HANA = 'X'`. If you cannot access `se37` use `sa38` and call `RSFUNCTIONBUILDER` (the report behind `se37`).

PS: *The requests on `DD03VV` are awfully slow, probably due to missing optimzation for complex requests on ABAP dictionary views.*

Answer (score 3):

If I had to give only one DDIC structure, I would give this one:

```
FDT_TEST_DDIC_BIND_DEEP_S
```

It contains many elements of miscellaneous types, including nested ones, and it exists in any ABAP-based system (it belongs to the "BASIS" layer).

As it contains some data and object references in sub-levels which are invalid in RFC, you'll have to copy it and remove those reference fields.

There are also these structures (column "TABNAME") with fields of some interest:

```
TABNAME               FIELDNAME      Description
--------------------  -------------  ------------------------------------------------
SFW_BF                FROM_RELEASE   elementary built-in type
SAUNIT_S_ALERT        WHEN           data element 
SAUNIT_S_ALERT        HEADER         structure 
SAUNIT_S_ALERT        TEXT_INFOS     table type
SAUNIT_PROG_INFO      .INCLUDE       include structure SAUNIT_S_TADIR_KEY
SKWF_IOFLD            .INCLU-FLD     include structure SKWF_IO
SWFEXPSTRU2           .INCLU--AP     append structure SWFEXPSTRU3
APPEND_BAPI0002_2_2   .APPEND_DU     append structure recursive (append of BAPI0002_2) (unique component of APPEND_BAPI0002_2_2)
SOADDRESS                            Structure with nested structures on 2 levels
```

Some structures may not be valid in some ABAP releases. They used to exist in ABAP basis 7.02 and 7.52.

Comment: Can data types like "ref to class" get used in RFC?

Comment: No, data and object references can't be used in RFC -> I remove them from my answer. As FDT_TEST_DDIC_BIND_DEEP_S contains some references, you'll have to copy it and remove the reference fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try the function module RFC_METADATA_TEST...
It has some deeply nested parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In Se80 under Enterpise service browser, you will find examples of Proxy structures that are complex DDIC structures. With many different types.

Example `edo_tw_a0401request`
Just browse around, you will find something you like.

Answer (score 0):

I found `STFC_STRUCTURE` in the docs of [test_datatypes](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC/blob/404a14bfda3097926a77ac5bcee372ea3e4aab61/tests/test_datatypes.py) of PyRFC.

Works find for testing, since it is already available in my SAP system. I don't need a dummy rfc for testing. Nice.